# Meaning of metrics from the Cat Nodes API in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am looking for more information on node stats. I want to know the meaning of the metric `*Time` like metrics under `_cat/nodes`?

The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/cat-nodes.html) says it is `time spent in fetch phase`. I get it that this is the time spent in fetching, but since when? Is it since the server started or over some time window like sum over last 1 hour?

Is the same explanation applicable to `*Time` metrics?

I am using ES 2.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

It is the total time spent fetching documents from shards ever since the node started.

That metric is reset every time you restart your node.